# How can I flatten a pyspark dataframe joining on linked ids

Tags: join, pyspark, flatten, record-linkage

I have a PySpark dataframe of ids showing the results of a series of linkage operations. It shows how the records within a series of dataframes are linked across those dataframes. An example is as below where df_a represents the first dataframe in a pair comparison and df_b the second. link_a is the id of a record in df_a that links to an entry in df_b.

So the first row is saying that dataframe 1 entry 100 links to entry 200 in dataframe 2. In the next row entry 100 in dataframe 1 links to entry 300 in dataframe 3.

| df_a | df_b | link_a | link_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 100 | 200 |
| 1 | 3 | 100 | 300 |
| 1 | 4 | 100 | 400 |
| 1 | 5 | 100 | 500 |
| 2 | 3 | 200 | 300 |
| 2 | 4 | 200 | 400 |
| 2 | 5 | 200 | 500 |
| 3 | 4 | 300 | 400 |
| 4 | 5 | 400 | 500 |
| 1 | 2 | 101 | 201 |
| 1 | 3 | 101 | 301 |
| 2 | 3 | 201 | 301 |
| 2 | 3 | 202 | 302 |
| 1 | 3 | 103 | 303 |
| 1 | 5 | 103 | 503 |

In the real table there are many dataframe comparisons and across all the dataframes 100000's of links.

What I am trying to achieve is to reformat this table to show the links across all the dataframes. So you can see in the above example that 100 links to 200, 200 to 300, 300 to 400 and 400 to 500. So all 5 records link together. Not all cases will have a record in each dataframe so in some cases you will end with incomplete chains empty values.

The end result would look like.

| df_1 | df_2 | df_3 | df_4 | df_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 |
| 101 | 201 | 301 | - | - |
| - | 202 | 302 | - | - |
| 103 | - | 303 | - | 503 |

I will then use the above to add a common id to the underlying data.

I have gotten part of the way to this using a series of joins but this seems clumsy and quickly becomes difficult to follow. I have now run out of ideas as to how to solve so assistance getting closer or even to a full solution would be gratefully received.

Comment: The long table is better than the wide one. You should probably learn to work with than instead of recreating the table. The wide one would not cover the case where there are 2 links between same tables. E.g. df_1.col1 links to df_2.col5 AND df_2.col6. The long one can deal with such case, this is why it's better.

Comment: I've edited the question but ultimately I want to be able to add a common unique id to all the links.  In this situation the scenario you describe shouldn't occur anyway.